# Laravel - edit form updated checkbox value

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I have a form created for editing a Trip. One field is 'Public' which is a boolean. When public is checked as true, I can't get it to show and update on the edit form.

**addTrip.blade.php**

```
  <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('is_public', 'Make Trip Itinerary Public') !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('is_public', 'value'); !!}
</div>
```

**editTrip.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group"> Make  Public
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_public" class="switch-input" value="{{$trip->is_public}}" />
    </div>
```

**TripController**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'name'         => 'required',
      'email'        => 'required',
      'destination' => 'required',
      'startdate'   => 'required',
      'enddate'     => 'required',
      'user_id'     => 'required',

    ]);

    //Update Trip
    $trip = Trip::find($id);
    $trip->name = $request->input('name');
    $trip->email = $request->input('email');
    $trip->destination = $request->input('destination');
    $trip->startdate = $request->input('startdate');
    $trip->enddate = $request->input('enddate');
    $trip->is_public = $request->has('is_public');
    $trip->save();

    return redirect('trips')->with('sucess', 'Trip Updated');
}
```

Comment: What happens if you rename `public` to something else? For example, `is_public`. I believe `public` is a reserved word and you'll want to steer clear of using that in your code. Example: `$trip->is_public = $request->has('is_public');`

Comment: updated my columns name to is_public, but still appearing unchecked in edit view even though it should be checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input type checkbox has the property `checked`. if you want to make it checked then you have to add the property.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_public" class="switch-input" value="{{$trip->is_public}}" {{ $trip->is_public == 1 ? 'checked' : null }}/>
```

> use whatever value you have stored in your database instead of 1.